# Unable to separate 2 div rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning HTML and CSS, and am having trouble figuring our how to include a horizontal space to separate both rows, and fix the misalignment/sizing problem. Both rows are currently attached together, and when I remove `<div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px">`, the misalignment is fixed but the rows are still together.

Can any one help me out?

HTML:

```
    <div id="featuredcities">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/singapore.jpg" alt="singapore">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Singapore</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Amazing culinary experience and <br>efficient business ecosystem in this <br>tiny cosmopolitan country.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/bangkok.jpg" alt="bangkok">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Bangkok</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">A bustling neon-lit city that combines tradition and modernity.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/shanghai.jpg" alt="shanghai">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Shanghai</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Blend of East meets West <br>in this high energy metropolis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/hcmc.jpg" alt="ho chi minh city">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">HCMC</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">The "Paris of Asia", Ho Chi Minh City is <br>as much historical as it is modern.</p>
      </div>
    </div><!--End of 1st div row-->

    <!--2nd div row-->
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/seoul.jpg"  alt="seoul">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Seoul</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Famous for pop culture, <br>vibrant shopping and <br>historical palaces.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/bangkok.jpg" alt="bangkok">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Bangkok</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">A bustling neon-lit city that combines tradition and modernity.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/shanghai.jpg" alt="shanghai">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Shanghai</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Blend of East meets West <br>in this high energy metropolis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/hcmc.jpg" alt="ho chi minh city">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">HCMC</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">The "Paris of Asia", Ho Chi Minh City is <br>as much historical as it is modern.</p>
      </div>
    </div><!--End of 1st div row-->

  </div><!--End of Community-->   
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
#images .col-md-3 {
  height: 570px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your first "row" (#featuredcities) is not a div with the `.row` class...I'd start there.

Comment: Also, IDs must be unique...you can't use them more than once....and all your images have the same ID. **Validate your code!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this HTML for your first div

`<div id="featuredcities">`

Add the class `row` to it.

`<div class="row" id="featuredcities">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" id="featuredcities">

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/singapore.jpg" alt="singapore">
      <a href="#"><p id="text">Singapore</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Amazing culinary experience and <br>efficient business ecosystem in this <br>tiny cosmopolitan country.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/bangkok.jpg" alt="bangkok">
      <a href="#"><p id="text">Bangkok</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">A bustling neon-lit city that combines tradition and modernity.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img id="image" src="images/shanghai.jpg" alt="shanghai">
      <a href="#"><p id="text">Shanghai</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Blend of East meets West <br>in this high energy metropolis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <img id="image" src="images/hcmc.jpg" alt="ho chi minh city">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">HCMC</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">The "Paris of Asia", Ho Chi Minh City is <br>as much historical as it is modern.</p>

    </div>
</div>
<!--End of 1st div row-->

  <!--2nd div row-->
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px"> <!-- padding top is all you need -->

    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <img id="image" src="images/seoul.jpg"  alt="seoul">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Seoul</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Famous for pop culture, <br>vibrant shopping and <br>historical palaces.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <img id="image" src="images/bangkok.jpg" alt="bangkok">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Bangkok</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">A bustling neon-lit city that combines tradition and modernity.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <img id="image" src="images/shanghai.jpg" alt="shanghai">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">Shanghai</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">Blend of East meets West <br>in this high energy metropolis.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <img id="image" src="images/hcmc.jpg" alt="ho chi minh city">
        <a href="#"><p id="text">HCMC</p></a>
        <p id="summarytext">The "Paris of Asia", Ho Chi Minh City is <br>as much historical as it is modern.</p>

    </div>

</div>
<!--End of 2st div row-->
```

always try to keep your code cleaner.. I recommend you you study really good bootstrap grid system [Bootstrap-grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

edit:
Your images ID is "image" , and in your css you're calling "#images"  ... ?

Answer (score -1):

You could either change it from padding-top to margin-top, or you could also add in a 
 tag in between the two divs.